# Having problem with certain keyboard characters on ubuntu installed on a laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu on my Toshiba laptop. It installed fine, the only problem I am having is that certain key on my keyboards are not appearing, e.g., when I type forward slash I get -, when I press + I get ¡, when I press is equal to I get ¡, could you please let me know how can I fix this problem,

Comment: move to superuser/ubuntu?

Comment: @James, why the question mark? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably chose the wrong keyboard configuration during Ubuntu installation.

[wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu) has a tutorial for setting the keyboard configuration without having to reinstall.

3rd result for Google: ubuntu change keyboard layout